# Android copy .mp4 video using media codec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

This is my first question so please let me know if I missed anything!

I want to copy the video using android Media Codec class. (form.mp4 -> to.mp4)

I did decoding video and audio . but i have no idea how to incorde video and audio. I already saw http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ this page. But i can't find simple example.

```
mFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", mMetadata.V_WIDTH,mMetadata.V_HEIGHT);
            mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH, mMetadata.V_WIDTH);
            mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT, mMetadata.V_HEIGHT);
            mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, (int) mMetadata.BIT_RATE);
            mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, mMetadata.FRAME_RATE);
            mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
            mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, mMetadata.I_FRAME_INTERVAL);
            videoEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
            videoEncoder.configure(mFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            videoEncoder.start();
```

I did Media-codec start. but I don't know how connect row data of video. please save me from this hell.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If, as the question title says, you just want to *copy* the video, you don't need to decode and re-encode it.

Comment: My first step is just copy. but finally what i want is .... Apply Color effect in origin video and add subtitle. And Receive .mp4 format Edited Video. Is it impossible using Media Codec?

Comment: It is entirely possible. It is not entirely simple, unfortunately. The DecodeEditEncode example demonstrates the basic H.264 handling, some of the other examples show MediaExtractor and MediaMuxer at work for the .mp4 file conversion. Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) demonstrates color effects (using Camera as input). Rendering text for subtitles requires some additional work.

Comment: I wonder about this code. why using COLOR_FormatSurface??

(private static final int OUTPUT_VIDEO_COLOR_FORMAT =     MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface;)

is that code occur Black Video surface??

Comment: The output file have no actual Video just black video.. ( While testing ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java)